# Query Large Table With Large Number Of Matches In Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of emails with about 800 million entries, and I need to match it against a list of about 100,000 emails.  The email entry in the database is indexed.

What would be the best query to do it?  I've tried creating a temporary table with the entries I want to match against and then doing a SELECT against that and the main table, but it seems like it should be faster than it is - multiple queries seem to slow down.  Any suggestions?

The server is running MySQL 5.5.27 on CentOS 6.3.

EDIT: Here are the creation statements:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable (Email varchar(50)) 
CREATE INDEX tempindex ON temptable (Email)
```

And here's my query:

```
SELECT temptable.Email FROM temptable, biglist WHERE temptable.Email = biglist.Email
```

And here's the EXPLAIN result:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | temptable | index | tempindex     | tempindex | 53      | NULL                  |   21 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | biglist   | ref   | idx_Email     | idx_Email | 202     | datab.temptable.email |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Is this a regular thing or just once?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's still not what I'm looking for"? Also, which version of mysql?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I'll clarify the original post.

Comment: Take a look at this article, it might be helpful: http://tagide.com/blog/2012/08/how-to-handle-large-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
select emailaddress,
       (case when bg.emailaddress is NULL then 'MISSING' else 'PRESENT' end)
from TEMPemail te left outer join
     BigTable bg
     on te.emailaddress = bg.emailaddress
```

Your idea to put the emails in a temporary table is a good one.  The query might perform better if you have an index on the temporary table as well as the bigger one.

Comment: The index was a big help.  I also found that splitting the query up helped as well - made sure it didn't go to temp disk to do the query.  Thanks!